# MigraDoc not adding page breaks automatically

Tags: c#, pdf, migradoc

I am tasked with refactoring an old MigraDoc project written by a dev that is no longer with my company, and am having problems with the following bit of code..

```
var Split = new String[1];
Split[0] = "||";
if (invoiceObject.Note != null)
{
    var Lines = invoiceObject.Note.Split(Split, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    for (var i = 0; i < Lines.Count(); i++)
    {
        if (i > 0)
            lineItemParagraph.AddLineBreak();

        lineItemParagraph.AddText("" + Lines[i].Replace(" ", " ").Replace("|", ""));

    }
}
```

This is working and it's taking a double pipe delimited notes fields and breaking it out into new lines as expected. The issue is that for very large note fields, the rendered PDF only has 1 page and the text just runs off the page. (The item I am testing with has enough data in the notes field for 20+ pages in the rendered PDF).

**Edit**

The code is inside of a text frame defined like this.

```
TextFrame lineItemFrame;
this.lineItemFrame = section.AddTextFrame();
this.lineItemFrame.Height = "3.0cm";
this.lineItemFrame.Width = "8.0cm";
this.lineItemFrame.Left = "0cm";
this.lineItemFrame.RelativeHorizontal = RelativeHorizontal.Margin;
this.lineItemFrame.Top = "9.0cm";
this.lineItemFrame.RelativeVertical = RelativeVertical.Page;
```

The Text frame is inside of a section that is defined like this. Looking through the code, it appears this is the only section on the PDF. Do I perhaps need more sections?

```
section = this.document.AddSection();
section.PageSetup.StartingNumber = 1;
```

I can't figure out how to make MigraDoc add the page breaks for me automatically.

Am I missing something painfully obvious?

Comment: I think your code snippet misses the important parts. Is the text in a table?

Comment: Sorry, I am very new to migradoc as this was not my project..I looked through it and this code is inside of a `TextFrame` that is defined in my edited question.

Comment: TextFrames do not break to the next page. Updated my answer (TextFrames were missing at rev. 1). If the text is too long for a single page, then a single `TextFrame` cannot be used. Use paragraphs or tables to get automatic page breaks. If you stick to TextFrames, you will need several TextFrames - and splitting the text is up to you. I understand that changes to code from a different developer can be difficult, but I'm afraid there is no simple solution.

Comment: I see, thank you for the information @ThomasH! I will attempt to move to a paragraph only and not a paragraph inside of a text frame.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MigraDoc adds page breaks automatically - with two exceptions: TextFrames do no break, table rows do not break. Tables break between rows only.

Comment: Thank you for responding! Please see my edited question for additional details

Comment: Removing the paragraph from the text frame fixed with issue with no page breaks! Thank you!!!!